# calculus word problem regarding derivatives

Tags: calculus

Let P = f(t) represent the US population in millions in year t.

$f(2005)= 296$

1) what does $f^{-1}(296)$ means and in what units? 
My answer was : This is the Us population in year 296, and the units is millions of people. However, it was wrong, I think I mixing it up so I need a clarification please.

2) The derivative  $(f^{-1})'(296)$ = ____ ( units ) ? and what does it mean?

My answer was $(f^{-1})'(296) = \frac{1}{f'(2005)}$ what shall I do next?

Answer (score 0):

1) Over here let f^-1 be a function g where g(p)=t
Where p is population in millions and t the year. 
So when we say g(296) we are actually telling the year in which the population was 296.

2) when we want g'(p) we are actually taking out dt/dp which is the rate of change of year per unit population. 
In other words it is the slope of the p-t graph.

Comment: The first part was totally clear.

Comment: The second part I tried and I ended up with an answer of 0.377. Is it right ?

Comment: Have you provided the whole question?